# Calculate intersection between 2 date ranges

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

i would like to calculate the number of free days (absences) in a specific week. I use an API that returns the following data:

```json
    {
    "count": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "11ec62ff1df2654d8bd6f1d234a6c496",
            "type": "HOLIDAY",
            "from": "2021-12-22",
            "to": "2021-12-23",
            "resourceId": "11ec46d6547a00728be3e1ed8ff29535",
            "createdAt": "2021-12-22T08:14:00"
        }
    ],
    "success": true
    }
```

These are vacation and sickness data. I have a weekly report where I need to calculate the number of absence days during that week. I need to find an easy way to calculate the number of absence days during the week.

I have tried by using https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.format.php and convert it into "z" format, but it doesn't look elegant and from performance perspective i think it's not best.

```php
//The week range 
$weekStart = new DateTime("2021-12-20");
$weekEnd = new DateTime("2021-12-24");

//The Planned absence
$absenceStart = new DateTime("2021-12-22");
$absenceEnd = new DateTime("2021-12-23");

//Specify the DateInterval for calculating the period
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');

//Need to add the interval to the end date in order to consider the end as well
$weekEnd->add($interval);
$absenceEnd->add($interval);

//Getting the 2 periods week and absence
$weekPeriod = new DatePeriod($weekStart, $interval, $weekEnd);
$absencePeriod = new DatePeriod($absenceStart, $interval, $absenceEnd);


$weekArray = array();
$absenceArray = array();

//put the day number format('z') into an array of the week
foreach ($weekPeriod as $i => $dt) {
    $weekArray[$i] = $dt->format('z');
}

//put the day number format('z') into an array of the absence
foreach ($absencePeriod as $i => $dt) {
    $absenceArray[$i] = $dt->format('z');
}

//get the intersection between both arrays
$ergebnis = array_intersect($weekArray, $absenceArray);

//calculate the number of entries
echo "The employee has <b>".count($ergebnis)."</b> free days in the week from 2021-12-20 until 2021-12-24";
```

This is returning the right information.

```
The employee has 2 free days in the week from 2021-12-20 until 2021-12-24
```

Can anyone please suggest if there is a better way or if i can tweak at least to make it more elegant and performat?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over the week array, absence array, then week array again (array_intersect), you could eliminate looping through the absence array and the second week array loop if that information is not needed. So you only have 1 loop instead of 3 should be more performant.

```php
//The week range 
$weekStart = new DateTime("2021-12-20 00:00:00");
$weekEnd = new DateTime("2021-12-24 23:59:59");

//The Planned absence
$absenceStart = new DateTime("2021-12-22 00:00:00");
$absenceEnd = new DateTime("2021-12-23 23:59:59");

//Specify the DateInterval for calculating the period
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');

//Getting the available period
$weekPeriod = new DatePeriod($weekStart, $interval, $weekEnd);

$availableDayCount = 0;

//put the day number format('z') into an array of the week
foreach ($weekPeriod as $dt) {
    // Filter out days the employee is absent.
    if($dt < $absenceStart || $dt > $absenceEnd) {
        $availableDayCount += 1;
    }
}

//calculate the number of entries
echo "The employee has <b>" . $availableDayCount . "</b> free days in the week from " . $weekStart->format('Y-m-d') . " until " . $weekEnd->format('Y-m-d');
```

Additionally, it didn't appear to be providing the correct information (maybe I am wrong?). Your question states it came to 2 days but I count 3:

- 2021-12-20
- 2021-12-21
- 2021-12-24

(The 22nd and 23rd being absent)

If that is incorrect, you can change `$weekEnd` to 2021-12-23 (I added start/end of day times so the entire day is counted).